# Rails, Passenger and Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, passenger, webfaction

Has anyone figured out how to use authlogic with passenger? On the Github Binary Logic page there is a note that says it does not work, the problem is that when you log out, it does not really log you out -- you continue to be logged in -- I have researched this -- and it seems to happen to most people.

But I would have thought by now someone would have figured out how to fix this issue.

Any helpers out there?

This especially an issue on Webfaction as that Passenger is your only option for serving your files.

Most guides tell you it is the fault ofthe "active record store" but i can not seem to find a tutorial that shows you how to fix this.

my set up is rails 2.3.10 and passenger 2.2.15

Any help would be great.

thx

Comment: Do you have some links to your "research"?

Answer (score 1):

The authlogic readme states that it's an issue with Passenger and 2.1.x, but this is not the version you are using. What is the problem?

Comment: It seems that I can't log out. When I log out I am still logged in.

Answer (score 1):

We use Authlogic in production with Phusion Passenger. The problem you mentioned turned out to be a cookie bug in Rails. The most recent Rails 2.3 and 3.0 releases fix this problem.